# What objects are interactive on the playing board?

Tags: hearthstone

When playing against slow opponents I spend most of my time clicking the interactive areas of to boards like the catapult, bonfire and farm.

I have multiple times though I had found them all but then found a new place to click.

So what are the places you can click on each board to have something happen?

Comment: Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147473/when-you-click-on-the-scenery-in-hearthstone-does-your-opponent-see-it

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Orgrimmar board**

- Zeppelin - tumbles when clicked
- Rock by the zeppelin - tumbles more and more when clicked like it's going to fall
- Gates - can be closed and opened
- Vines by the gates - If you hack them enough they spread a bit
- Forge - clicking black smoke will exhaust / "ignite" it
- Banner by the forge - flops a bit when clicked
- Catapult - you can put rock in it and fire it on the enemy,than cork it back and re do

**Stranglethorn board**

- Diamond in the statue - if you click enough it will fall out
- Eyes in the dark beneath the statue - makes some roar or hiss sound
- Vines on the gates - if you click enough you can cut them
- Skull on top of the gates - makes drumming sound
- Coconut tree over the gates - coconuts can fall off
- Waterfall - clicking water makes splashing sound and effect and can create rainbow
- Bushes - will make them move a bit
- Tent door - makes snoring sound
- Tent roof - clicking the pelt will make it "jump",dust off and change(leopard,zebra,tiger)
- Fire by the tent - Clicking can ignite it

**Stormwind board**

- Glass around church doors - can be broken
- Lamp near the church - turn on/off
- Church roof - bell sounds
- Armory sign - one chain can be broken by clicking
- Armory door - open/close
- Armory roof - one tile can fall out
- Armory window - turn lights on/off
- Bushes near church and armory - can be clicked
- Clock tower roof - boards can be broken
- Clock - makes ticking sound,adds a minute,and should be set to current time
- Well - splashing effect until the bucket falls in,also one of the bricks can be broken off
- Gryphon - Moves and follows you mouse when clicked
- Banner under the Gryphon - swirls when clicked
- Haystack - hay straws flying effect when clicked
- Crates behind haystack - can be broken

**Pandaria board**

- Kite - moves a bit when clicked
- Wooden stake that holds the kite - you can pull it out and lose your kite :(
- Round paper light - moves a bit when clicked and makes a sound
- Window light - on left building can be turned on/off no sure for the right building window
- Doors on watermill - makes opene/close sound
- Water wheel - you can help turning it by clicking
- Gong - makes weak gong sound,each few hits it makes louder effect
- Bush with flowers near gong - you can pop flowers
- Fruit on farm - can be squashed
- Water(irrigation) on farm - makes squashed fruit grow back(as different fruit)

**Naxxramas board**

- Floating crystal - moves when clicked,after enough clicks it starts to crack
- Egg sacks - can be poked,after enough clicks spiders crawl out from it
- Spider eyes in the dark - when they appear you can click on them,usually spider just makes hissing sound and hides,sometimes bats flew out and rarely the spider bites your cursor
- Skull,left eye - diamond falls out
- Skull,scalp - tapping sound
- Skull,left tusk - if you click it it just moves a bit,but if you click and hold the sludge will start pouring out from skull
- Mushrooms - you can poke them,after enough clicks they release green gas
- Sludge pit - bubbles
- Sludge still,2 hatches - they can open/close
- Sludge still,valve - can be turned,if turned enough times and if both hatches are closed the still will boil and release the sludge,otherwise it just releases steam
- Sludge still,screw - 2nd screw from the left can be turned until it pops out
- Sludge puddle - splashes

**Goblins vs. gnomes board**

- Switches and red button on teleporter - pressing red button will spawn vegetable,fish,boot,diamond,bomb,banana,kite or chicken-bot inside teleporter.Setting of switches doesn't appear to matter.
- The teleporter corner - The tiny screw laying on the board can be clicked and will screw itself into the hole above it.
- Laser gun - can be turned around and fired.Shooting at enemy hand will play a "Ouch!" sound. Shooting under the satellite dishes near the rocket will launch it.
- Satellite dishes - play scanning sounds.
- Furnace - holding furnace doors opened few times can ignite both of the nearby fireworks

**Blackrock Mountain board**

- Left lava pool - clicking rune combinations can make maul/periscope/inflatable animal sink/surface.

  - valve on the periscope can be turned
  - inflatable animal can be popped
- Right lava pool - Upper chain fills up the pool,lover one drains it.
- Dragon eggs - can be squashed
- Torch - can be lit or extinguished
- Anvil - Clicking makes it glow more and changes nearby weapons(axe/sword/polearm)
- Shield - Can be turned in to a round one

...And you can poke the dirt on the ground,which you will end up doing most when waiting.

Comment: Does the other player see your interactions?

Comment: He doesn't.It would be very distracting if you were playing your turn and someone would keep clicking around.

Comment: Clicking the forge smoke actually turns it off, and clicking again turns it back on.

Comment: :( cant upvote or accept again sadly

Answer (score 2):

Every corner "location" of the board has at least one interactive point:

**Stranglethorn:**

- the jewel can be removed from the eye socket, making it drop in the jungle;
- the menacing eyes in the jungle disappear when clicked;
- clicking on the vines on the gate cuts them;
- the eyes on the skull above the gate lighten up;
- the waterfall, when clicked, creates a rainbow;
- the fire can be put out by clicking on it;
- the pelt on the tent changes when clicked, from tiger to leopard to zebra and back to tiger.

**Stormwind:**

- clicking on the stained glasses of the cathedral breaks them;
- the streetlight can be put out;
- the bucket falls in the well when clicked;
- the inn sign moves;
- the door of the inn gets closed when clicked and you can turn off the lights inside too.

**Pandaria:**

- the kite moves in the wind;
- the wheel in the mill moves when clicked;
- the gong makes a sound when clicked.

**Orgrimmar:**

- the zep moves in the wind;
- you can play with the catapult by putting rocks on it.

This is what I remember, I'll update when I can test a little more.