# When you click on the scenery in Hearthstone, does your opponent see it?

Tags: hearthstone

When you click on the stuff around the board in Hearthstone, does your opponent see it happening too?  For example, sometimes there is a church in the top left where you can break the windows.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, only you see your clicks and effects on the game board's 'environment'.

However, there are some opponent's actions that are visible to you, e.g: minions on the battlefield or hero powers are highlighted when your opponent hovers their mouse over them.

Comment: As well as hovering over their cards and the order of their cards. Which can be used to your advantage if you know what cards has been used and if they target your face with a card and then decide not to, you will have the advantage of knowing that it is a "deal damage/freeze" card. (Unless they are bluffing).