# What Easter Eggs are in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

Lets keep it simple. I have not been able to find any forums with facts about Easter Eggs in Hearthstone, so I would love to know the following.

**Are there any Easter Eggs in Hearthstone?**

**And if so, which Easter Eggs are there in Hearthstone?**

NOTE: That I am not interested in knowing the definition on Easter Eggs.
(look here for a discription of an Easter Egg in a video game: http://www.gamesradar.com/100-best-easter-eggs-all-time/)

Comment: In older games, in the early days of Easter Eggs, all of the [playing board clickables/interactions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139142/) would have definitely counted as Easter Eggs. Also, +1 for a timely question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So from the looks of things, there aren't actually many Easter Eggs in Hearthstone, at least not many discovered yet. It is indeed a little surprising, but to be fair, Hearthstone isn't exactly the largest of games. The closest things to Easter Eggs are actually more like hidden references to the lore of Warcraft.

- If Cairne Bloodhoof is played against a warrior, he says the line "Garrosh, you are not fit to rule the horde" rather than his usual line.
- If Illidan Stormrage is played against a druid, he says the line "Hello, brother" rather than his usual line.
- Millhouse Manastorm, the hero in the tutorial, says a line "Just you wait until I have 10 mana!" This is a reference to the old Millhouse Manastorm card, which had "Battlecry: Put a 'Mega-Blast' card in your hand." Megablast is a 10 mana card that deals 5 damage to all enemies. [Reference](http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/213z68/found_a_fun_little_easter_egg_on_the_tutorial/cg9k9hx)
- In the Hearthstone credits, there are personalized cards for team members of Hearthstone, many of which seem to reference aspects of the individual person. [Reference](http://hearthstone.blizzpro.com/2013/10/15/hidden-gems-in-hearthstone/)
- The opening video has an 8 cost Pyroblast; it's now 10.
- If you click on the vegetables long enough you can get a boot.
- If you play Dire Wolf Alpha against the Big Bad Wolf, your wolf whimpers after the Big Bad Wolf scared him. [Reference Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbat6D1KwGs)

There are of course individual cards that are references to things in World of Warcraft rather than the actual lore, one of the most obvious being Leeroy Jenkins, but I wouldn't necessarily define these kinds of things as Easter Eggs.

If individual unlisted extras are discovered, feel free to edit this question and tack them on here, so they can be easily organized. However, from what my research could find, these are pretty much the only ones discovered thusfar.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the in game scenery does stuff if you click on it.
If you shoot the rocket ship radar thing with the laser the rocket takes off.
If you fiddle with the iron grate the fireworks get set off.
Etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a reference to Indiana Jones and to Lord of the Rings:

Indiana Jones:
   -> there is a card called Harrison Jones, when you play him he says "this belongs into a museum", if he attacks he makes the sound of a whip.
   -> there also is a card that says "snakes, it has to be snakes"

Lord of the Rings:
   -> there is a card called Shieldbearer and when you play him he says "you shall not pass"

Answer (score 0):

The brave archer when you click the card for its description it says "this is a bearly concealed reference" this references the Disney movie Brave

And the flesh eating ghoul may be a reference the the anime Tokyo ghoul